# Redmine - adding git repository for a project

Tags: git, repository, redmine

I installed Redmine in a windows server.
I want my redmine user to have the ability to create their own repository.

I followed this http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories#Git-repository

From what I have learned about redmine repository that I have to clone the repository to a the directory file of the redmine server.

So I think that I will have to do this for all the projects in my redmine because they don't have access to the server!

What do you suggest so my users will have the ability to add a git repository to their projects? Is there any way?

I hope it's clear

Hind

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, It's not possible.
Because to let users make their own Git repository, they should have permission to make it as OS user.

IMHO, split Redmine from Git, And give permission respectively. Git has no ACL out of the box, so use web application like Gerrit.